# What happened to sched_mc_power_savings

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, cpu

My laptop's battery performance is awful. I can get about an hour and a half out of it, so I've been looking for some ways to boost the power efficiency of my laptop.

I saw the tip to enable this:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings
```

But it does not exist on this installation. What happened to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be part of [laptop_mode (Ubuntu man page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/laptop-mode.conf.8.html): `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`

`more /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.conf`  and on the bottom it says:

```
# Control multi-core power-saving tunables for the process scheduler?
# Set to 0 to disable
CONTROL_SCHED_MC_POWER_SAVINGS="auto"
```

Answer (score 2):

Same for me! I have read that for somebody recompiling the kernel with the right processor family (core 2 instead of standard) resolved that problem (see http://www.linux-solved.com/post/Solved-Missing-sys-devices-system-cpu-sched-mc-power-savings-61510.html). However not for me! So my machine still exhausts 5Watts more than on other distris with a running scheduler.